# What is ./teardownFabric.sh in fabric-tools? and why we need to use this command?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I do not understand why we use **./teardownFabric.sh** before using **./stopFabric.sh** and **./startFabric.sh.**

Please give me a clear idea if you know it clearly.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got this from here: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/c7e94a64252e51625fe74c0e9a521a8d41281dd0/packages/composer-website/jekylldocs/installing/development-tools.md

> Note that if you've run the teardown script, the next time you start the runtime, you'll need to create a new PeerAdmin card just like you did on first-time startup.

**./teardownFabric.sh** will remove all docker files related to Fabric. That means your system will clean and you can start Fabric from the beginning.

Also, you can go through this code comment:https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/blob/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/teardownFabric.sh